# Код на неопределенное время зависает доходя до while

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть функции запуска приложений:

```
# Запуск MEmu
def start_memu():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if 'memu.exe' in proc.name().lower():
                print('MEmu уже запущен.')
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass

    print('Запуск MEmu...')
    os.startfile(r"labels\1.lnk")
    print('Ожидание запуска машины...')
    time.sleep(25)


# Запуск MicroSIP
def start_microsip():
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if 'microsip.exe' in proc.name().lower():
                print('MicroSIP уже запущен.')
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    print('Запуск MicroSIP')
    subprocess.call(r"start MicroSIP\microsip.exe", shell=True)


# Подключение к MicroSIP и MEmu
def connect_to_devices():
    global app, device
    app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r"MicroSIP\microsip.exe")
    client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
    sl = None
    devices = client.devices()
    for de in devices:
        sl = str(de.serial)

    device = client.device(sl)
```

Далее, в другой функции я их вызываю:

```
def call():
    memu_counter = 0
    print('Запуск программ')
    start_memu()
    start_microsip()
    connect_to_devices()
    while memu_counter < 81:
        # Ожидает окно входящего звонка MicroSIP
        try:
            print('Ожидание звонка')
            check = app.window().child_window(title="Отклонить", control_type="Button")
            call_window = app.window().Edit2.get_value()
            number = (((call_window.split('@'))[-2]).split())[-1]
        except IndexError:
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        ТУТ ЕЩЁ много кода, вне except.
```

Код печатает один раз `print('Ожидание звонка')` и зависает на какое-то время (около -40-50секунд) и дальше начинается итерация, Ожидание звонка начинает печататься каждую секунду.

Код зависает только в том случае, если одно из двух приложений было закрыто и код его открывает.

Comment: Может, антивирус?

Comment: @Qwertiy Антивируса нету, а защита **Windows** вся отключена.

Comment: А что за `Application` то вообще? Может вы ему `GUI` своим `while` стопорите, если он там есть? И ещё это очень плохо - просто "проглатывать" исключения. Исключения нужно печатать на экран либо логировать в файл. Я так понимаю у вас какое-то исключение вылетает, а вы даже не видите - какое именно, а просто ждёте секунду и продолжаете цикл. А там может что-то полезное написано. Сделайте хотя бы `except as ex: print(ex)`.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я много раз уберал `try/except`, чтобы понять ошибки. Там только ошибки, что информации никакой нет или таймаут. в цикле я жду появление окна, оно проверяет, есть ли окно (вызовет исключение, если нету).

Comment: @CrazyElf Кстати, похоже ошибка действительно кроется в `app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r"MicroSIP\microsip.exe")`. Сейчас путём принтов и удалений, понял, что именно на этой строчке код останавливается на некоторое время.

Comment: `GUI` в любых приложениях работает только в одном, главном потоке. Если вы главный поток заняли циклом в своём коде, `GUI` не сможет отрисовываться. У вас есть примеры из документации, как правильно использовать это `Application`?

Comment: @CrazyElf [Документация](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html)

Comment: Надо разбираться. Возможно, я и не прав про `GUI`, ведь это другое приложение. Как это всё вместе работает навскидку не очень понятно.